# Not waking up after closing the lid

Tags: system

So it started happening after I installed 5.1 and updated the kernel to 5.0.

Always when i close the lid it suspended and when i opened back i showed me lock screen now it doesnt show the lock screen, i have to press the power button to show me the lock screen.

Another thing is that if i leave the lid closed for more than 30 minutes it doenst wake up even if i press the power button.

My laptop has a led that shows if the laptop is powered on and when it suspended the led blinked on and off but now it just stays on always even if the laptop is suspended

Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1):

I went back to an older kernel and it fixed everything

4.15.0-72-generic

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem very similar to this so I downgraded the kernel and xorg hwe package and installed the generic 5.4.1 kernel using Ukuu and so far it works flawlessly. It turns out my issue was related to the xorg hwe updates and not the newer kernel.